# Failed to Generate PDF Documentation for the Boost C++ Library

Tags: c++, boost, doxygen

I have recently tried to generate a PDF documentation for the `Boost` library. But I failed on both `Windows 10` and `Fedora 28`, with the error message below (this is the error message on my `Fedora 28`):

```
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/predef/check/../tools/check/predef.jam:46: Unescaped special character in argument $(language)::$(expression)
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/xpressive/doc/Jamfile.v2:49: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/winapi/doc/Jamfile.v2:19: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/winapi/doc/html
Building the variadic_macro_data docs with automatic index generation enabled.
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/variant/doc/Jamfile.v2:18: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/utility/doc/Jamfile.v2:38: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/unordered/doc/Jamfile.v2:61: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/unordered/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/units/doc/Jamfile.v2:213: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/type_traits/doc/Jamfile.v2:61: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/type_index/doc/Jamfile.v2:34: Unescaped special character in argument <xsl:param>boost.root=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/type_index/doc/Jamfile.v2:36: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html
Building the tti docs with automatic index generation disabled. Try building with --enable-index.
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/test/doc/Jamfile.v2:143: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/static_assert/doc/Jamfile.v2:38: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/stacktrace/doc/Jamfile.v2:42: Unescaped special character in argument <xsl:param>boost.root=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/stacktrace/doc/Jamfile.v2:44: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/Jamfile:53: Unescaped special character in argument <format>pdf:<xsl:param>boost.url.prefix=http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html
Building the Spirit docs with automatic index generation disabled.  Try building with --enable-index.
Building the Spreadsort docs with automatic index generation disabled. Try building with --enable-index.
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/libs/sort/doc/Jamfile.v2:90: in modules.load
*** argument error
* rule doxygen ( target : sources + : requirements * : default-build * : usage-requirements * )
* called with: ( autodoc :  : <doxygen:param>PROJECT_NAME=Sort <doxygen:param>RECURSIVE=NO <doxygen:param>ENABLE_PREPROCESSING=YES <doxygen:param>EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF=YES <doxygen:param>EXTRACT_ALL=NO <doxygen:param>EXTRACT_PRIVATE=NO <doxygen:param>HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS=YES <doxygen:param>MACRO_EXPANSION=YES <doxygen:param>SORT_MEMBER_DOCS=NO <doxygen:param>SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES=NO <doxygen:param>MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES=0 <doxygen:param>VERBATIM_HEADERS=NO <doxygen:param>WARNINGS=NO <doxygen:param>WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED=NO <doxygen:param>WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR=YES <doxygen:param>WARN_LOGFILE=AutoDoxywarnings.log <xsl:param>boost.doxygen.reftitle=Boost.Sort C++ Reference )
* missing argument sources
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/tools/doxygen.jam:627:see definition of rule 'doxygen' being called
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:325: in load-jamfile
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:145: in project.find
../Jamfile.v2:96: in modules.load
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:325: in load-jamfile
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:113: in load-parent
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:464: in initialize
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:306: in load-jamfile
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:145: in project.find
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:618: in load
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/home/krantz/soft/boost_1_67_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

This message is printed out when I run `b2 pdf` in `$BOOST_PATH/doc/pdf`.

Is it possible to fix such an error, or is there a pre-built version on the Internet? I have found an old version on SourceForge, but it has not been updated since 2014, so I wonder whether I can get a version for `1.64` or later.

Comment: Looks like to me a problem in the boost scripts. I don`t see that there is a problem with doxygen, but the way boost scripts try to create some documentation looks like to give an error.

Comment: @albert I guess so. I have already tried several versions of Boost (1.64 ~ 1.67), but they fail with quite similar messages, and I wonder whether the developers had well tested their scripts, and thus these doc just won't compile on my pc.

Comment: Same problem w/ boost 1.77

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these can be fixed [by changing](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2015/04/221686.php)

```
import doxygen ;
import quickbook ;
```

to

```
using doxygen ;
using quickbook ;
```

and by [quoting the string containing a colon](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2018/03/241901.php) (e.g., `<cxxflags>"/std:c++14"`) in `Jamfile.v2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am not using Boost (not even C++) in development these days, so it may take me some time to install back all the required environments and verify the solution before I can accept this answer.

Comment: @RuifengXie: No worries!